# PyProj giving RuntimeError: b'argument not numerical or out of range'?

Tags: pyproj, runtimeerror

I have this string:

```
string = '+proj=lcc +a=6371200.0 +f=0.0 +pm=0.0 +x_0=5632642.22547 +y_0=4612545.65137 +lon_0=-107.0 +lat_1=50.0 +lat_2=50.0 +lat_0=50.0 +units=m +axis=enu +no_defs'
```

Then I do:

```
my_proj = pyproj.Proj(string)
```

It gives me this error:

> RuntimeError: b'argument not numerical or out of range'

Anyone can help me?

Python 3.7 with pyproj 1.9.5.1; but also tested on pyproj 1.9.6 (same error).

Comment: Why are lat 0, 1 and 2 == 50? What CRS are you trying to implement?

Comment: Hum, apparently it would be the projection of the NARR dataset (in NetCDF4)

Answer (score 1):

Since I still want to use pyproj 1.9.6 because Pyproj 2.1.3. still hiccup with the packages that depend on Qt (matplotlib, Jupyter, etc). https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/268

I had the same issue, and came across these pages:

- [github.com/OpenDrift/opendrift/issues/94](https://github.com/OpenDrift/opendrift/issues/94)
- [github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/1191](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/1191)

Basically, it seems to be an issue in version 5.0.0 of proj4. My problem was resolved by downgrading to version 4.9.3, as suggested in the post above.

```
conda install proj4=4.9.3
```

Pyroj and packages that depend on Qt now work perfectly on the same environment!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend upgrading to pyproj 2.2.0.

More examples here: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.2.0rel/examples.html

```py
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> pyproj.Proj( '+proj=lcc +a=6371200.0 +f=0.0 +pm=0.0 +x_0=5632642.22547 +y_0=4612545.65137 +lon_0=-107.0 +lat_1=50.0 +lat_2=50.0 +lat_0=50.0 +units=m +axis=enu +no_defs')
Proj('+proj=lcc +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-107 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=50 +x_0=5632642.22547 +y_0=4612545.65137 +R=6371200 +units=m +no_defs', preserve_units=True)
```